# How can I make a substitution on the line of first occurrence of a match only?

Tags: awk, sed, text-processing

I have a file that looks like this

```
000099990000 Carlos C
000099990000 Ana B
000099990000 Ana A Test
000099990000 Ana B
000099990000 Carlos C
```

I want to find the first occurrence of `Ana B` only, then replace the `9999` part of the matching line with `1111`.

I'm running the following line:

```
sed -i '0,/Ana B/ s/9999/1111/' file.txt
```

but I'm getting the following result:

```
000011110000 Carlos C
000011110000 Ana B
000099990000 Ana A Test
000099990000 Ana B
000099990000 Carlos C
```

So `sed` is replacing all lines up to first occurrence of `Ana B`. What is wrong with my command?

Comment: It works for me; does your input file have Windows line endings? Try `dos2unix file.txt` before running the sed command.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried dos2unix but Im still getting the wrong result:
000011110000 Carlos C
000011110000 Ana B
000099990000 Ana A Test
000099990000 Ana B
000099990000 Carlos C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed '0,/Ana B/ { //s/9999/1111/ }' ip.txt
000099990000 Carlos C
000011110000 Ana B
000099990000 Ana A Test
000099990000 Ana B
000099990000 Carlos C
```

- `{ //s/9999/1111/ }` the `{}` here allows to group commands to execute only when `0,/Ana B/` condition is satisfied
- `//` will reuse the last used regex, same as using `/Ana B/` - this will ensure only lines containing `Ana B` are changed

You can also use `awk` here:

```
$ awk '/Ana B/ && !c++{sub(/9999/, "1111")} 1' ip.txt
000099990000 Carlos C
000011110000 Ana B
000099990000 Ana A Test
000099990000 Ana B
000099990000 Carlos C
```

- `/Ana B/ && !c++` if line contains `Ana B` and if `c` is zero (the default value for uninitialized variables)

  - because of `++` next time `c` will be `1` and condition will fail (note that very large matches of `Ana B` could result in overflow and `c` becoming `0` again)
- `sub(/9999/, "1111")` change `9999` to `1111`
- `1` idiomatic way to print content of `$0` (input record)

Comment: Thank you, this worked on the sample. Base on your tip I'm trying to run the follwing script but its not working (no changes on file), any insight?
`file="input.txt"
while IFS= read line
do
 echo $line
 awk -v var="$line" '/var/ && !c++{sub(/0301060096/, "0301060029")} 1' corrected.txt > corrected.temp && mv corrected.temp corrected.txt
done < "$file"`

Comment: `/var/` will try to match line containing `var`, you will have to change that to `$0 ~ var`